# Rogue's Tumble PHB vs HotFL

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, rogue

Which version of Tumble is correct? The powers are exactly the same Level 2 Utility, Encounter, Req. Acrobatics training. The difference is in the effect.

Player's Handbook (PHB) ~ Effect:You can shift a number of squares equal to one-half 
your speed.

Heroes of the Forsaken Lands (HotFL) ~ Effect: You shift up to your speed.

Neither of these has an Errata. So which is held to be correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The text in the compendium agrees with the HotFL with the following note:

"Update (9/30/2011) Updated in Class Compendium"

That seems pretty clearly to me that there is errata in the class compendium that updates the PHB1 power to the HotFL text.

Checking the [Class Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/dra/201106rogue) for the Scoundrel Rogue (an update to the PHB1 classes), it agrees with the HotFL power description.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer glad someone can find an errata. Guess WotC needs to errata the errata.

Comment: @Jeff Technically, it's an update, not errata, in my opinion. Plus, if you have a question like this, the compendium is usually the authoritative and updated source to check.